# What was this set of RPG tools called?

Tags: tools, dnd-3e, product-identification

Years ago, I found a set of free RPG tools on someone's website. It included:

- A random treasure hoard generator for D&D third edition.
- A random dungeon map generator. It created black-and-white dungeons that resembled oldschool dungeon maps, and you could set options like density of rooms and the number of rooms in the dungeon. Each room was numbered, and could be filled with randomly generated monster encounters and treasure based on the treasure tables per level.
- A town/settlement generator based on D&D third edition... or was it a random tavern generator?

I seem to recall that there was both a downloadable Windows program and an web version. I found it around 2000-2003, definitely third edition based.

What were these tools called, what was the site they came from, and are they still available anywhere?

Comment: There've been a lot of RPG tools, especially for D&D 3.5. Perhaps someone can recognize it based on this descriptions, but can you give us any more information, like roughly the year(s) you found it, or some detail regarding the map generator (was it random, tile-based, drawing-based, etc)?

Comment: @BESW Updated with what information I can remember.

Comment: It's feeling like a person might actually recognize it now! (In fact, I'm feeling like *I* might recognize it...)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Found it! It was called *Jamis Buck's Dungeon Generator*, and the URL was [http://www.aarg.net/~minam/dungeon.cgi](http://web.archive.org/web/20080202074327/http://www.aarg.net/~minam/dungeon.cgi). There was an offline version for Windows, as well as a treasure generator, town generator and NPC generators for D&D 3.0 and 3.5.

That site is gone, but a good replacement is http://donjon.bin.sh/d20/dungeon/.

Comment: you should best answer your own answer at this point.

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith I tried earlier, but it told me "You can accept your own answer tomorrow." Sounds quite philosophical.

Comment: @jonahthandrain that makes sense and lol.

Comment: Using the internet archive, you can reach a snapshot of the site that [sometimes works](http://web.archive.org/web/20080725192612/http://www.aarg.net/~minam/dungeon.cgi).

Answer (score 14):

if you prefer Jamis Buck's generator, myth-weavers has been hosting his tools online...

http://www.myth-weavers.com/generate_dungeon.php

(the rest are under the Site Tools menu)

Answer (score 8):

Jamis Buck has open-sourced his apps and you can find [the generators on github](https://github.com/jamis?tab=repositories) if you want executable/offline versions.